# EXPTIME-complete propositional satisfiability problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

SAT is NP-complete, QBF is PSPACE-complete, DQBF is NEXPTIME-complete. Is there any extension of QBF or restriction of DQBF that is EXPTIME-complete?

Added later: a definition of DQBF can be found here: https://www.react.uni-saarland.de/publications/sat14.pdf

Comment: The qustion would be more useful if you added the definition of DQBF, which is probably not familiar to everyone here.

Comment: This is not quite what you seem to be after, but there are propositional modal logic with an EXP-complete satisfiability problem, such as PDL.

Comment: I would think that if there were some way to represent Horn-SAT succinctly, that might help.  The trouble is whether or not that is possible.

Comment: (This is also not what you said you were looking for, but consider:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_game#Circuit_games )

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find the reference anymore but I remember that deciding the following game is EXPTIME-complete. It is a two-player game played on a (CNF)-formula where the set of variables is partitioned into (X,Y). At their turn, Player 1 (resp. 2) can swap the truth value of one variable in X (resp. Y). They start from a given (non satisfying) assignment and Player 1 wins whenever the formula becomes satisfied (while Player 2 wins if, say, the game cycles or after $2^n$ moves).